# can VSCode extension use sqlite3 to read data?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I want to read SQLite DB while VSCode extension loading.

the `extension.ts` looks like:

```
'use strict';

import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
console.log(sqlite3);
```

1. atfer install by `npm install sqlite3`, the extension encounter error:

```
Activating extension `undefined_publisher.example` failed:  Cannot find module '/path/to/proj/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
```

2. according [node-pre-gyp](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/blob/v0.12.0/lib/util/abi_crosswalk.json#L1758-L1761), I reinstall sqlite3 by `npm install sqlite3 --target=10.0.0`, and make sure that `node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node` exists. 
   But vscode hang in `require('sqlite3');`

**Is there anyway can load data from sqlite in extension?**

Comment: I have not tried yet but https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vscode/sqlite3 might work as it is under the @vscode namespace?